# Get text from file and output in html (Simple own CMS)

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a file. In this file is one string.

Then the string gets outputted on a normal web page. 
It works for simple things, but I want all strings inside one file and not one file per string.

My code so far:

```html
<a class="navbar-brand"><?php echo file_get_contents("test.txt") ?>
```

It loads the content of the `.txt` file and posts it.
Currently inside the `text.txt` file is:

```html
Hello World!
```

But I want it like a CMS style / .ini type of way like:

```html
companyname     Testcompany
button          Hello World!
copyright       Copyright by Headman
greeting        Hey there, greetings!
year            2018
```

And to get the current right string chosen and outputted on the right place.

How can I get those strings correctly?

Comment: read your file line by line, and then print the lines one by one in any loop till you reach end of file. Then you can print the text in exact format.

Comment: or maybe use `json` for better data structure

Comment: Maybe use JSON format for your file?

Comment: @kerbholz ahhh, you won

Comment: if you only want to use the format in the file, use <pre> but not  A tag。

Comment: I would seriously consider using Markdown files for your use case, rather than just a .txt file. It's designed to be converted into HTML easily, and most implementations support front matter, so you can use that to store any additional data beside the page content.

Comment: Hey there. I will check out JSON,. Thank you!

Comment: I think this would be simpler with php, as with JSON I always need to get the element ID… in php I could just get "companyname" etc.?